# Expletive there

Tags: word-choice, clauses, who-whom

"__________ twelve million immigrants entered the United States via Ellis Island."

(A) More than      (B) There were more than

In the above, I understand the correct one is (A). However, if "there" has no function, and the actual subject is "twelve million immigrants", why not (B) ?
"Twelve million immigrants" is the subject for "were"; and the whole clause "There were twelve million immigrants" is the subject for "entered"; in this case I don't need a connector like "who".
I am saying that the sentence can be correct with (B): it does not have to be,
"There were more than twelve million immigrants **who** entered the United States via Ellis Island" to be correct.

Comment: Or change entered to entering

Comment: You don't mean expletive. That means a swear word or an interjection.

Comment: Can you re-phrase at least part of 'X immigrants…' and say how that could relate to either '(A) More than…' or '(B) There were more than…'?

Answer (score 1):

"__________ twelve million immigrants entered the United States via Ellis Island."

(A) More than (B) There were more than.

A) is correct. **B) requires a change to the sentence:**

"There were more than twelve million immigrants ***who*** entered the United States via Ellis Island."

Answer (score 0):

While "there" doesn't refer to anything, it's not accurate to say it "has no function". It functions as the subject of the main clause of the sentence.

"*There were more than twelve million immigrants*" is a complete sentence with a subject and a verb with tense. "entered" is a second verb with tense, but it has no subject, so it's not grammatical.

In the correct version, "More than twelve million immigrants" is the only subject, and "entered" is the only verb with tense, so they go together. In the incorrect version, "twelve million immigrants" is the *complement* of "There".